# Set header on a specific page with .htaccess

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, http-headers

Trying to use `.htaccess` to set a header when on a specific page of the website.

I've tried various methods to set the header, but none of them result in the header being set in the response.

**Method 1:**

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^\/glossary\/$ glossary
Header Set Test-Header "success" env=glossary
```

I've also tried a simpler version where I try to match 'glossary' in any part of Request_URI

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI glossary glossary
Header Set Test-Header "success" env=glossary
```

**Method 2:**

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/glossary/'">
    Header Set Test-Header "success"
</If>
```

**Method 3:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/glossary\/
RewriteRule ^ - [ENV=GLOSSARY]
Header Set Test-Header "success" env=GLOSSARY
```

---

I've also output Request_URI in a header in order to confirm that Request_URI has a value:

```
Header set Test-Output-Request_URI "%{Request_URI}e"
```

This results in the Header being set, as expected:

```
Test-Output-Request_URI: /glossary/
```

I'm not much of an expert in .htaccess, nor regex, but normally I'm able to plug away and find a solution. Not this time though. From what I've read, it seems like all of these methods should work, but I'm obviously missing something.

This is Apache 2.4.35

Not sure if it makes a difference, but this is a WordPress site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you in Apache 2.4+

```
<If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ m#/glossary#">
    Header Set Test-Header "success"
</If>
```

Instead of `==` operator for string comparison, we are using `=~` operator for regex matching here.

Comment: This one isn't working for some reason. Can you think of anything that would cause this not to output the header when on that page?

Comment: I do have more rules in my .htaccess, and I was removing as much as possible in order to troubleshoot, and then I saw your updated answer. That seems to work! I'll accept your answer once I'm sure that it's working. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Since I am now using `THE_REQUEST` this will not get affected by other rules

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation! I had gotten my .htaccess rules down to only the bare minimum needed by Wordpress and the `REQUEST_URI` solution still didn't work, but `THE_REQUEST` works perfectly. Answer accepted. Thanks again!